# How to detect in application if Android system is upgraded?

Tags: android

My application need to be able to detect if system is upgraded successfully, but it could be caused by the same version of system image, is there any way to check if system upgrade is successfully done no matter whether the os version is changed ?

Answer (score 1):

Your [Application.onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) can compare your package's last update time against a stored last update time. If the times are different, then the app had been "updated" (even if the version did not actually change).

For example, it can call a `wasUpdated` method like the one below. (This method will always return true the first time it is ever called, but you can modify it to not do that.)

```
static final String PREF_LAST_UDATE_TIME = "pref_last_update_time";

static boolean wasUpdated(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    long storedLut = prefs.getLong(PREF_LAST_UDATE_TIME, -1);
    long lut = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).lastUpdateTime;
    if (storedLut != lut) {
        prefs.edit().putLong(PREF_LAST_UDATE_TIME, lut).apply();
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```